# WFF WebGet vs. WebInvoke(Method = "GET")

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, webget

All posts I have seen regarding these two attributes focus on the different HTTP verbs available with WebInvoke. But when GET is specified as the method, is there any difference between these two, is there any benefit of one over the other, or is it purely semantic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF WebGetAttribute vs WebInvokeAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072556/wcf-webgetattribute-vs-webinvokeattribute)