# Is WebGet functionally equivalent to WebInvoke(Method = "GET")?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, webinvoke, webget

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072556/wcf-webgetattribute-vs-webinvokeattribute) question already asks what I'm asking, but I want some clarification on the answer.

The answer states that `WebGet` and `WebInvoke` are similar, and that the primary difference is the `Method` parameter.

But if the `Method` parameter is set to `"GET"`, is it actually functionally equivalent, or are there other differences?

Comment: The documentation for [WebInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) says: "If you want a service operation to respond to GET, use the WebGetAttribute instead." So it seems that WebInvoke is only intended to be used with POST, PUT, or DELETE.

Comment: One difference: The internal [System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.AddOperationsFromType](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Services/System/Data/Services/Providers/BaseServiceProvider.cs,d5f831be05db2b2a,references) method treats WebGet as GET and WebInvoke (even if its Method is GET) as POST.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Yeah, I read that, but the code already contains `WebInvoke(Method="GET")`, so I want to make sure I'm not breaking anything before I change

Answer (score 2):

They are simply marker attributes and end up being 100% functionally equivalent. The only thing that interprets these attributes is the `WebHttpBehavior::GetWebMethod` method and its functionality is simply:

```
internal static string GetWebMethod(OperationDescription od)
{
    WebGetAttribute webGetAttribute = od.Behaviors.Find<WebGetAttribute>();
    WebInvokeAttribute webInvokeAttribute = od.Behaviors.Find<WebInvokeAttribute>();
    WebHttpBehavior.EnsureOk(webGetAttribute, webInvokeAttribute, od);
    if (webGetAttribute != null)
    {
        return "GET";
    }
    if (webInvokeAttribute == null)
    {
        return "POST";
    }
    return webInvokeAttribute.Method ?? "POST";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not.

I just spent few hours trying to replace WCF DataContractJsonSerializer with Newtonsoft JsonSerializer using MessageFormatter based on [this](http://jeroenhildering.com/2014/03/21/replacing-wcf-datacontractjsonserializer-with-newtonsoft-jsonserializer/) and 
 [this](https://github.com/carlosfigueira/WCFSamples/tree/master/MessageFormatter/MessageFormatter) samples

found out (the hard way) there IS difference in using `WebGet` and `WebInvoke(Method="GET")`.

With `WebInvoke` the request goes through different pipeline in WCF stack, trying to deserialize the expected message (method `IDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest()` gets invoked) which is not the case with `WebGet`.

The lesson learned: use `WebGet` for `GET` operation